# Knockout Binding does not work for password input in Chrome 33.0.1750.154m

Tags: google-chrome, knockout.js, binding, passwords

I have Chrome Version 33.0.1750.154 m and knockout 3.0.0

I am trying a thing like below, but binding doesn't work for the password input. 
I have tried it in Internet Explorer, it works, but it doesn't work in chrome. 
 The password property is always empty, I couldn't find the reason.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Password" />
            <span data-bind="text:Password"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password Again</label>
        <div>
            <input type="password" data-bind="value: PasswordAgain" />
            <span data-bind="text:PasswordAgain"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var user = function () {
    this.Password = ko.observable('');
    this.PasswordAgain = ko.observable('')
};

ko.applyBindings(new user());
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EKTD/)

Comment: It is working fine here with using: Chrome Version 33.0.1750.146 m and it is still working after upgrading to Version 33.0.1750.154 m...

Comment: Why does not it work in my chrome ? This is so nonsensical :(

Comment: I found the reason. It didn't work due the kaspersky virtual keyboard extension for chrome. I disabled it, and it works now.

Comment: Please post an answer with your findings so other people can learn from your experience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. It didn't work due the kaspersky virtual keyboard extension for chrome. I disabled it, and it works now.